# Image Map - Country

Tags: html, css, dictionary

Can anyone help me how I can code below map so when you click on a specific area it can take you to a paragraph next to it with a brief description of that city?

My code so far:

```
<section class="section-places"> 
    <h2>places</h2> 
        <p><a name="bangkok-map"></a> This is Bangkok..... </p> 
        <p><a name="chiangrai-map"></a> This is Chiang Rai..... </p>
        <img class="thai-map" src="resources/css/img/thailand861891_1920.png" alt="Thai-Map" usemap="#mapbangkok">

<map name="bangkok"> 
    <area shape="circle" coords="50,0,82,126" alt="Bangkok" href="#"> 
</map>
```

[image: Thailand Map]

Comment: <section class="section-places">
            <h2>places</h2>
            
            <p><a name="bangkok-map"></a> This is Bangkok..... </p>
            <p><a name="chiangrai-map"></a> This is Chiang Rai..... </p>
         
            <img class="thai-map" src="resources/css/img/thailand-1861891_1920.png" alt="Thai-Map" usemap="#mapbangkok">
            
            <map name="bangkok">
            <area shape="circle" coords="50,0,82,126" alt="Bangkok" href="#">
                        
      
            </map>

Comment: that is my code so far.. i cannot get my head around how to use coords.. and also how to style the points after? 
any help would be much appreciated :)

Comment: hey @WlliamD thanks for your reply. 

sorry i cannot see the code you have cleaned up? it still appears the same. can you post again please? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually use Dreamweaver to create image maps, but some of my students use this online editor, Easy Imagemap Generator, http://imagemap-generator.dariodomi.de/.

Once you have your image map generated, give each related paragraph a fragment identifier, so the Bangkok paragraph would have an id of 'bangkok', and the href value in your sample above would be #bangkok.

Hope this helps.